# Merging unallocated space to existing partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Recently was trying to remove Ubuntu from a dual-boot Mac I had, wound up deleting the Ubuntu partition but now the 500GB used for it are just unallocated space according to GParted.

I'm running Ubuntu from a live flash drive .iso but GParted still will not let me resize the partition containing the MacOS.

[Image of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWNL1.png)

[Partition containing MacOS doesn't allow me to increase/decrease size of the partition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG1ZI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need unallocated space adjecant to the partition you want to grow. This is not the case, there is a 23GB linux-swap partion between your MacOs-partition and the unallocated space.

Since you removed Ubuntu this linux-swap shouldn't be needed anymore and you could simply remove it, you'll have to swap-off the partition (which can be done through the right-click menu in Gparted) before. Then you'll be able to grow your partition.

If you want or need to keep this linux-swap for any reason, move it to the end of the disk (also here you need to swap-off first) so the unallocated space will be adjecant to your MacOs-partition.